# How to find header control of repeater in c# .net?

Tags: c#

I am working on asp.net c# . I am trying to find the header control in c# . But I am getting object not set to an instance of an object . My code is

```
    public void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl ulSubNav2 = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("da-sliders");
            ulSubNav2.Style.Add("background", "transparent url('DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif') repeat 0% 0%");
            ulSubNav2.Style.Add("width", "100%");
            ulSubNav2.Style.Add("height", "400px");
        }
    }
```

relevant HTML Code

```
  <HeaderTemplate> 
      <div id="da-sliders" class="da-slider" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound">
  </HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Try out `((Repeater)Sender).Controls[0]`

Comment: can u post the HTML used? maybe there is an error with the ID of the header control

Comment: <HeaderTemplate>
<div id="da-sliders" class="da-slider" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound">
    
</HeaderTemplate>

Comment: `da-sliders` is definitely not the ID of your header control since only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for a control-ID in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the system failed to find the control with the name you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a "runat" tag to the div like this :

```
<div id="da-sliders" class="da-slider" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound" **runat="server"**>
```

Now in your ItemDataBound you have access to the div item in the HeaderTemplate.

Comment: @user1511098 Without `runat="server"`, there's no way for the code behind to access that control. Perhaps your sliding jquery doesn't work because the control ID changes? Then there's a way around that. Accessing a div without `runat="server"`? There's no way around that.